# Can LINQ be asked to Skip/Leave particular indexes?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops

I myself am a big fan of LINQ. The art of brevity is reflected in LINQ. Also in .Net we say that LINQ is a step ahead of loops or we can say LINQ is loops++.

But is it really this way?

Why i am being judgmental is because i was trying to convert this for loop code to LINQ but was confused that do LINQ skip/Leave indexes?

```
double[] NMD = {3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 65.0, 34.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 65.0, 34.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 65.0, 34.0 };

for(int i=1; i<NMD.Length-1; i+=2)
   NMD[i] = NMD[i]/10;
```

Here i am asking for loop to start from index 1 and stop at the penultimate value and also skip value by 2. So can we do this in LINQ. IMO I don't think so But I'll be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: If you need to run an update, your `for` loop is the cleanest solution.

Comment: I agree with @dasblinkenlight, but in addition, if you already have working code it's not worth rewriting it just to use LINQ.

Comment: @Ian: I disagree. In this case it's very likely that the original code is *buggy* (because it doesn't modify the last element, even if it has an odd index!) Rewriting your code in more functional style can help eliminate these issues (because you state the desired output, rather than the algorithm to achieve it).

Comment: @NiklasB. Sure, if your code is buggy then rewrite it, but I specifically stated that if you have working code then you shouldn't rewrite it.

Comment: @Ian: You don't know ahead of time if your code is buggy. Testing can only show the presence of errors, not their absence. Using a more functional style helps here, but I agree you have to do a lot more work to achieve this than just to replace `for` loops by LINQ expressions.

Comment: @NiklasB. Second guessing the intention of code, and rewriting it to what you assume it's meant to do, rather than what it's actually meant to do, has caused many problems in my experience. If you suspect that you have buggy code, the first thing you should do is verify that it is buggy. Using a paradigm that may produce less buggy code is pointless if you don't know what the code is supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: @Ian: Of course, if this is part of the specification, it's perfectly fine. My point is that using functional style has a lot of advantages and it's a good thing to refactor existing code to make better use of it. But as I said, you need to do more than just replace `for` with `Select`. If you do it properly and use immutable data and higher-order functions where appropriate, you can sure raise the quality of your code and make it easier to adapt to parallel execution later on.

Comment: @Nikhil: Is it indended that the last value will be uneffected, even if it has an odd index? By the way, if you tell us what you want to achieve by this code, we can probably show you a way to rewrite it in a more functional style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test the index inside `Select` and choose your action accordingly:

```
NMD = NMD.Select((x, i) => i % 2 == 1 && i < NMD.Length - 1 ? x / 10 : x).ToArray();
// => { 3, 0.5, 6, 6.5, 34, 0.3, 5, 0.6, 65, 3.4, 3, 0.5, 6, 6.5, 34 }
```

However, as you maybe already figured out by looking at the size of this statement, LINQ is *not* a conceptual improvement here, because you can only create new sequences with it and not mutate existing sequences.

That said, the `for` loop is fine and actually more readable, in my opinion. Rather than saying that "LINQ is loops++", you should refine it to "LINQ is sequence generation++" or "read-only iteration++".

If you want to use LINQ efficiently, you have to rethink and redesign your code in a more functional way (and use immutable data structures, for example) instead of just replacing every `for` loop with a LINQ expression. If you do that consequently and sensibly, you can increase the quality of your code and make the switch parallel execution less problematic in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
var NMD = new[] {3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 65.0, 34.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 65.0, 34.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 65.0, 34.0 };
NMD = NMD.Select((n, i) => i % 2 == 1  ? n / 10 : n).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will just throw away the first and last value.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Edited according to your comment. You also have no need to check if i < NMD.Length - 1 if array length is odd.

Comment: The array doesn't have to be of odd length, so you have to check anyways. I'm not sure if it's actually intended that the last item stays unaffected, though...

Answer (score 0):

You can select only items with odd indices with `NMD.Where((x,i) => i % 2 == 1)`, but you won't be able to update the values in the array.

Comment: what about start from 1 till penultimate?

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not really the best tool for this kind of task - changing data inplace, and only some of them. But if you really want to, you can do it like this:

```
NMD = NMD.Select((x, i) =>
{
    if (i < 1 || i >= NMD.Length - 1 || (i % 2)==0)
        return x;
    else
        return x / 10;
}).ToArray();
```

Remember that with linq, you won't change the existing sequence, you'll replace it with a new one.